# Pinescript-Newbie: Problem with "IF"-command

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i try to code my first pinescript and i'm stuck:
Why does this not run?

I want do draw a dot when two lines cross up or cross down.
I want see the green dots only, when the crossdown is above the zero-line and i only want see the red dots, when crossup is below the zero-line.
x1 ist crossover and x2 is crossunder. x1 and x2 was delcared in the code further up in the script.

```
if x1 > 0
    plot(x1 ? circleYPosition : na, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=6, color=dotColor, title='Dots')
if x2 < 0
    plot(x2 ? circleYPosition : na, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=6, color=dotColor, title='Dots')
```

When i use the code without the if-comand then the dots were shown.
So i think the problem have to do woth the if-command.

I've got this errors:

line 67: Cannot call 'operator >' with argument 'expr0'='x1'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'const float' is expected;

line 68: Cannot use 'plot' in local scope.;

line 70: Cannot call 'operator <' with argument 'expr0'='x2'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'const float' is expected;

line 71: Cannot use 'plot' in local scope.

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here.

`ta.crossover()` and `ta.crossunder()` returns `bool`. And you cannot compare `bool` with `float` as you do here.

```
if x1 > 0
if x2 < 0
```

Your second problem is, you cannot use the `plot()` in local scope.

What you can do is, apply your condition directly to the `series` parameter of the `plot()`.

After you fix your first problem, you cna move that condition to the `series` parameter of the `plot()` (if necessary).

Then it would be:

```
plot((x1 > 0) and x1 ? circleYPosition : na, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=6, color=dotColor, title='Dots')
plot((x2 < 0) and x2 ? circleYPosition : na, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=6, color=dotColor, title='Dots')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you for your support.
For me as a newbie it is difficult to follow and understand your explanation.
I changed the code as you suggested. However, I still get these error messages.
You described something of two problems. Do I understand correctly that the changed code fixes the second problem but not the first?

```
x1 = ta.crossover(blueMACD, orgMACD) and barstate.isconfirme
x2 = ta.crossunder(blueMACD, orgMACD) and barstate.isconfirmed
plot((x1 > 0) and x1 ? circleYPosition : na, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=6, color=dotColor, title='Dots')
plot((x2 < 0) and x2 ? circleYPosition : na, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=6, color=dotColor, title='Dots')
```

[SCreenshot_Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epRW3.png)

EDIT:
Where do I get the value where the lines cross to get a float value?
I understood that a numeric value is not possible with a bool.
I only want see the red dots, if they are above 0 and the green dots if they are below 0.

[Screenshot_MACD-lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq7Si.png)